# Is there a badge for soldiering on?

Tags: discussion, badge-request

I just had a question that was thrown into review for two weeks, lots of comments, and about three manual resubmits to get it put up. I don't want to be a [karma (rep?) whore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19522#19522) by linking to it here, but let's just say that while my original question wasn't totally in-line with Stack Overflow policy, it wasn't much different than out-of-date versions I was trying to replace.

In general, it felt like I was under assault by the tyranny of the crowd as I think most voters just skimmed it instead offering an edit or telling me how it differed from the prior examples.

I tried to stay humble and eventually the excellent @Brad Larson swooped in, did great rewrite, and cleared all the downvotes. I waited a week and then through 50 rep points on a bounty for the question before I finally got an answer to a question a few people had asked previously.

Anyway, is there a badge that rewards persistence like this? Because after such an arduous review process, I kind of feel like I deserve one :p

Comment: The journey is the reward my friend. That and you got an answer to your question.

Comment: Sounds like the community did a lot of work for you.  (Not that that's bad, it's great that the community was able to help you.)  I'm not seeing where you provided valuable content.  Why should you get a badge for the community helping you?  Your reward is the answer to your question.

Comment: @Servy I think review was a bit silly to begin with and that the brunt of the work fell on me.  The actual question wasn't of great importance to me, but I was curious and it seemed like other people would benefit too.  You can check my SO account if you are interested.

Comment: The brunt of the work **should** fall on you. It's you that is asking for our help, and you should have to work at least as hard as we do to get it. You're asking people to donate their time and knowledge to you at no cost; the least you can do is put effort into asking a decent question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question in question: *[How do you programmatically access the ambient light sensor on Mac OS X 10.5+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625495)*

The original question:

> (As others have been marked as dupes please note that this is NOT a
>   duplicate of [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050821/accessing-macs-sensor-data) nor [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239496/disable-ambient-light-sensor-screen-dimming-programmatically-on-os-x): those solutions are broken as of OS X 10.5 and
>   above!)
>
> Does anyone know of the private API and any related libraries for
>   accessing the ambient light sensor data?

[Revision History](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17625495/revisions)

If anyone deserves a badge it's Brad Larson, for taking the time to perform the salvage operation...